# Generalized Fermat equation for signature [4,5,7]

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

The generalized Fermat equation has been solved for many signatures.  But, I can't find a determination that the signature $[p,q,r]=[4,5,7]$ has no solutions.  Is this signature
still an open problem?

$\chi=1/4+1/5+1/7<1$

$x^p+y^q=z^r$

$gcd(x,y,z)=1$

$p,q,r\ge3$

The equation has only finitely many solutions with a bound given by the Darmon-Granville Theorem. Many other signatures have already been eliminated like
$$
[p,p,p], [3,5,5], [4,5,5], [3,4,7],
$$
and others.

Laisham and Shorey's 2011 result in their theorem 4 is that assuming Baker's conjecture there are no solutions to anything not in
$$
\{[3,5,] : 7≤  ≤ 23, \text{ prime}\}∪\{[3,4,]: \text{ prime}\} .
$$
This immediately implies at least a conditional elimination for $[4,5,7]$.

Comment: It has no known solutions, and by a general theorem has only finitely many solutions. I think it's still open, as to whether it has any solutions at all.

Comment: The finite solution bound is called the Darmon-Granville Theorem.  Many signatures have already been eliminated like (p,p,p), [3,5,5], [4,5,5], [3,4,7], and others.  The question is only about the signature [4,5,7].

Comment: I understand the question. My comment is all I know about 4, 5, 7. It may be all that is known about 4, 5, 7.

Comment: Laisham and Shorey's 2011 result in their theorem 4 is that assuming Baker's conjecture there are no solutions to anything not in $Q\epsilon\{[3,5,p]:7\le$ $p\le23, p$ prime$\}\cup\{[3,4,p]:p$ prime$\}$ This immediately implies at least a conditional elimination for [4,5,7].

Comment: It's probably best that when you post a question, you include right away everything you already know about it. If you don't get a satisfactory answer here after a few days, you might consider posting the question to MathOverflow (being certain to include a link at each site to the question at the other site).

Comment: See also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal_conjecture). It was updated  2 May 2020.

Comment: Yes, from Wikipedia: "The case $(x, y, z) = (3l, 3m, n)$ is direct for $l, m ≥ 2$ and $n ≥ 3$ from work by Kraus" has no solutions.  So, $[12,15,21]$ has no solutions. Then, absorb the cubes into the base number as in $x^{12}=(x^3)^4$. Hence, $[4,5,7]$ has no solutions.

Comment: I'm afraid you have the implication backwards, Pythagorus. If 4, 5, 7 has no solution, then, a fortiori, 12, 15, 21 has no solution. But it doesn't work in the other direction. 4, 4, 4 has no solution, but 2, 2, 2 sure does.

Comment: oops. You are right.  I guess $[4,5,7]$ is not, in general, in the Wikipedia list even though it intersects $(3l,3m,n)$ at $(12,15,21)$.

Comment: What about the 'easier' signature $[2,5,7]$?

Comment: It's not clear to me either why in Laisham and Shorey's 'Baker's explicit abc-conjecture and applications', set Q in Theorem 3 (Theorem 4 in the arXiv pre-print) doesn't include [4,5,7]. You could try asking on MathOverflow.